# Supersingular Isogeny Key Exchange broken?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

Found this report detailing a quantum algorithm for computing isogenies between supersingular elliptic curves.

https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2014/cacr2014-24.pdf

with the quote "recommendation to avoid using base curves defined over $\mathbb F_p$ in De Feo-Jao-Plut type schemes".

Is it correct then that 'Supersingular Isogeny Key Exchange' of De Feo is broken?

If so, as this is a fast moving field, are there any recommendations for alternate post quantum key exchange with reasonably good key size and speed?

Thank you.

Comment: New key-exchange: [This one perhaps](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/599.pdf)?

Comment: Now it is broken due to https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/975

Answer (score 7):

Sorry I will have to answer my own question.

I received a mail from Luca De Feo a moment ago.
"Nope, I discussed this at length with Jean-François Biasse, and we couldn't find a way to apply this kind of attack to SSIKE."

I'll leave this question around for reference for the next person who wonders.

Answer (score 5):

Also, the algorithm given in the mentioned paper has a complexity os $\tilde{O}(p^{\frac{1}{4}})$. The best known attack (As mentioned by de Feo, Jao and Plut) on the SSIKE is based on the claw finding problem (see below) and has a complexity of $\theta(p^{\frac{1}{6}})$.

Very interesting paper btw ;):
[Claw finding algorithm using quantum walk](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.2584v2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. This attack has been considered in De Feo's paper and their proposed parameters are resistant against this $O(p^\frac{1}{4})$-complexity attack.